# Why relative positioning of pic change position of one pic element?

Tags: positioning, tikz-pic

What is in design of my `pic` images wrong that its relative positioning change the position of (only) one internal node:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm, many]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, fit, scopes, positioning, quotes, shapes}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
            node distance = 0mm,
every label/.append style = {label distance=1pt},
                LC/.style = {draw, thick, {Circle[open,fill=white]}-},
gonTx/.pic = {\node (t) [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,
                         draw, fill=white, text width=7mm, rotate=-90] {};
              \draw[LC,thin,shorten <=-3pt] (t.side 1)  -- ++ (-0.5,0)
                    coordinate (t1) --
                    node (r)[draw, fill= white, minimum height=4mm,
                             inner sep=1mm, label=right:$R_{G}$, midway] {}
                    (t.south -| t1) --
                node (v) [circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                          minimum size=4mm, text=teal!60!black, midway] {$u$}
                                (t1 |- t.side 3) -- (t.side 3);
              \scoped[on background layer]
                \node (bb) [fill=gray!30, inner sep=2mm,
                            fit=(t.corner 1)(t.corner 2) (t.corner 3) ] {};%(z)
            \coordinate (-in)  at (t.south);
            \coordinate (-out) at (t.north);
              },% end of gonTx
}
% with out positioning
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (T) {gonTx};  %
\draw[Straight Barb-] (T-in) to ["signal" ']  ++ (-1.5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

% with relative positioning to given coordinate
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (b1) at (1,0);
\pic (T) [left=22mm of b1] {gonTx};  %
\draw[Straight Barb-] (T-in) to ["signal" ']  ++ (-1.5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The implementation is probably a bit buggy, I think I've seen such problems with "inheritance" of styles in other cases as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No doubt somebody will provide a more technical explanation and it must be noted that the implementation of `pic`s is *extremely* buggy. Knowing how to workaround bugs is essential for using them in any significant way.

However, I'm not certain that this is a bug as opposed to an inevitable result of their being `pic`s rather than, say, `node`s. A node has all kinds of features to help it end up in the right place without being explicitly told where to go. Nodes get placed according to a set of rules which mostly guess where they should be. In particular, the `anchor` of a node generally gets guessed correctly although obviously it must sometimes be specified explicitly. No algorithm is going to be able to get it right all the time.

`pic`s are much less sophisticated. What is happening here is, I think, that the individual nodes' `anchor`s are being chosen with regard to the placement of the `pic` as a whole, when there are no more proximal clues available to help make a better guess.

Because the `pic` is `left=... of ...`, the default anchor for nodes is `east`. This is what we see with the misplaced node. This doesn't happen with the other nodes in a noticeable way either because things are drawn relative to them (`(t)`), rather than their being drawn relative to other things, because their `anchor`s are explicitly given (`(v)`) or because their location is determined entirely independently (`(bb)`). If we override the default anchor for `(r)`, then it is no longer misplaced.

[image: replaced node]

Ideally, Ti*k*Z would use the positioning hints from the `\path` in preference to those from the placement of the surrounding `pic`. But I have no idea if this is realisable or not. In any case, `pic`s are, as I say, really quite buggy, and this may be just another `pic` bug.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, fit, positioning, quotes, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  node distance = 0mm,
  every label/.append style = {label distance=1pt},
  CB/.style = {thick, {Circle[open,fill=white]}-{Bar[width=3.4mm,line width=2pt]}},
  LB/.style = {-{Bar[width=3.4mm,line width=2pt]}},
  LC/.style = {draw, thick, {Circle[open,fill=white]}-},
  Lr/.style = {red,  very thick},
  Lb/.style = {blue, very thick},
  gonTx/.pic = {%
    \node (t) [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw, fill=white, text width=7mm, rotate=-90] {};
    \draw [LC, thin, shorten <=-3pt] (t.side 1)  -- ++(-0.5,0) coordinate (t1) -- node (r) [draw, fill=red, minimum height=4mm, inner sep=1mm, label=right:$R_{G}$, midway, anchor=center] {} (t.south -| t1) -- node (v) [circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, anchor=center, minimum size=4mm, text=teal!60!black, midway] {$u$} (t1 |- t.side 3) -- (t.side 3);
    \scoped[on background layer]
    \node (bb) [fill=gray!30, inner sep=2mm, fit=(t.corner 1)(t.corner 2) (t.corner 3) ] {};
    \coordinate (-in)  at (t.south);
    \coordinate (-out) at (t.north);
  },
}
% with out positioning
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic (T) {gonTx};
  \draw[Straight Barb-] (T-in) to ["signal" ']  ++ (-1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

% with relative positioning to given coordinate
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (b1) at (1,0);
  \pic (T) [left=22mm of b1] {gonTx};
  \draw[Straight Barb-] (T-in) to ["signal" ']  ++ (-1.5,0);
  \node at (b1) {b1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now I don't know, how I can forgot on `anchor` of resistor when I use it at voltage generator! I fill embarrassed ... Meanwhile I solve another problem (not present in question), why the `pic` is not vertically centered to coordinate. If I replace `rotate=-90` with `shape border rotate=-90`, this is achieved.

Comment: @Zarko It is much easier to see things like this in other people's code than it is your own ;).